# Error Handling in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have developed pyspark code which has several steps like reads data from hive table and create dataframes and do transformation and finally output the data into hive table.

I call pyspark shell from my UNIX script and after successful completion i want to put return code (success/Failure) into a text file.

Could anyone please let me know how to handle any errors in pyspark code. If any error occurs it put 1 into text file else 0 .

Example: Suppose database connection is not correct it should throw an error and put 1 in text file or any syntax error or any logical error.Basically i want any error then put 1 in file else 0 on successful completion.

Comment: want to capture any exception and put ERROR in a text file.